# Curl automated form filling

Tags: php, html, curl

If i have page like

xxxxxxx.org/2014/custom/code/code.php

and thers a text field and a sumit button

and the form tag for it is as follows

```
<form action="code.php" method="POST">
    <p class="formtext">
        Enter The Answer Here : <input type=text name="solution" />&nbsp;
        <input name="submit" type=submit class="btn btn-large    btn-success" value="Submit" />
    </p>
</form>
</div>
</html>
```

so what i want is the i need to pass the value of the text box to code.php using curl 
from my local host but it isnt working :/

Edit :

the content of the curl php file is :

```
  <?php
$name = "ASDF";

//$post = array(
//    'name' => urlencode($name),
//);
$post="solution=$name"; 
$ch =curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , 'http://www.XXXXXXXX.org/2014/custom/code/code.php');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST ,TRUE ) ;
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,TRUE);
echo $r = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

thers a login at
http://www.XXXXXXXX.org/2014/custom/code/code.php

but i have logged in manually and then i opened up the curl.php file in my browser it takes me to the login page again and after i log in again ,

the curl passes the value to www.localhost/code.php

and not to http://www.XXXXXXXX.org/2014/custom/code/code.php

Comment: use `curl_exec` function of php

Comment: Try `echo curl_error($r);` and see what the error is.

Comment: @AJReading returns no erro

Answer (score 0):

Actuall curl post parameter will be:

```
$post="solution=$name&submit=Submit";
```

You are missing `submit=Submit`.